# FlagSort - Divide and Conquer - Minor trouble

Tags: java, sorting, recursion, stack-overflow, divide-and-conquer

implementing a specific sorting algorithm, I ran into a problem even Google doesn't want to help me with... first **some words about the algorithm**:

The lion's share is about partitioning the input (array) to three parts: Picking two pivotal numbers (red and blue, asserting red <= blue), the elements of the partitions will be (1) less than both, (2) somewhere in between and (3) greater than both of the pivots. This is the part that works fine!

Sorting the array should take place recursively: Partitioning the input using arbitrary pivots before partitioning their partitions, thus ending up with particles of length 1 or 2 which are sorted per def. or rather can be sorted very easily.

**The problem is** now partitions of length >= 3 consisting of one key value: If partitioned again, regardless of what pivots were picked, all elements are put into the same partition afterwards, eventually running into a stack overflow. **That's why I thought of YOU being able to help me out,** as I'm sure there is a solution to this.

Mandatory JavaCode snippet: Partitioning - sorry for german debugging, too lazy to translate it too. IntTuple can only hold two integers; nothing too absurd.

```
public static IntTuple partition(int[] E, int left, int right, int red, int blue){
    if (red > blue) {
        int v = red;
        red = blue;
        blue = v;
    }
    System.out.println("Partition Eingabe: " + Arrays.toString(E) + " Links=" + left + " Rechts=" + right + " Rot=" + red + " Blau=" + blue);
    /*
     * Es gilt r <= b, also gilt für beliebige x...
     * ... x < r => x < b
     * ... x > b => x > r.
     *
     * Das Gerüst für diesen Algorithmus wurde kopiert von Folie 7-13
     */
    IntTuple result = new IntTuple (left, right); // rote und blaue Regionen sind leer
    int u = left; // weiße Region ist leer, die unbekannte == E[left...right]
    while (u <= result.v2) {
        System.out.print("E[" + u + "]: ");
        if (E[u] < red) {
            System.out.print("rot  ");
            swap(E, result.v1, u);
            result.v1++; // vergrößere die rote Region
            u++; // verkleinere die unbekannte Region
        } else if ((E[u] >= red) && (E[u] <= blue)) {
            System.out.print("weiß ");
            u++; // verkleinere die unbekannte Region
        } else if (E[u] > blue) {
            System.out.print("blau ");
            swap(E, result.v2, u);
            result.v2--; // vergrößere die blaue Region
        }
        System.out.print("Partition Schritt: [");
        for(int i = left; i < right; i++)
            System.out.print("" + E[i] + " ");
        System.out.println("" + E[right] + "]");
    }
    System.out.print("Partition Ausgabe: [");
    for(int i = left; i < right; i++)
        System.out.print("" + E[i] + " ");
    System.out.println("" + E[right] + "]" + " RotG=" + result.v1 + " BlauG=" + result.v2);
    return result;
}
```

Mandatory JavaCode snippet: Sorting

```
private static void flagSort(int[] E, int left, int right){
    System.out.println("Sortiere: " + left + " bis " + right);
    if(left < right - 1) {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        IntTuple v = partition(E, left, right, rnd.nextInt(50), rnd.nextInt(50));
        //IntTuple v = partition(E, left, right, E[left], E[left + 1]);
        flagSort(E, left, v.v1 - 1);
        flagSort(E, v.v1, v.v2);
        flagSort(E, v.v2 + 1, right);
    } else if((left == right - 1) && (E[left] > E[right])) {
        swap(E, left, right);
    }
}
```

Many thanks in advance for any ideas!

Regards, LDer

**MORE**: I came up with this hacky and awkward solution:

```
private static void flagSort(int[] E, int left, int right, boolean dual){
    if(left < right) { // Singleton or empty segments are already sorted!
        IntTuple v;
        if(dual) // The last step has produced only a single white partition.
            // Treat this partition with double pivot
            v = partition(E, left, right, E[left], E[left]);
        else    // The last step has produced more than one partition, go on normally.
            v = partition(E, left, right, E[left], E[left + 1]);
        // Analyze partitions
        if((left != v.v1) || (right != v.v2)) {
            // 2 or 3 partitions available. Descend further.
            flagSort(E, left, v.v1 - 1, false);
            flagSort(E, v.v1, v.v2, false);
            flagSort(E, v.v2 + 1, right, false);
        } else if(!dual) {
            // Only the white partition is not empty, partition it with double pivot
            flagSort(E, v.v1, v.v2, true);
        } // Last case: The only not-empty partition is white after partitioning with double pivot.
          // Description of the algorithm immediately implies that this consists of only one key value, thus is sorted.
    }
}
```

Can anyone help out in creating a more readable version?

**MORE**: This one looks way better:

```
private static void flagSort(int[] E, int left, int right, int offset){
    if(left < right) { // Singleton or empty segments are already sorted!
        IntTuple v = partition(E, left, right, E[left], E[left + offset]);
        // Analyze partitions
        if ((left != v.v1) || (right != v.v2)) {
            // 2 or 3 partitions available. Descend further.
            flagSort(E, left, v.v1 - 1, 1);
            flagSort(E, v.v1, v.v2, 1);
            flagSort(E, v.v2 + 1, right, 1);
        } else if (offset > 0)
            // Only the white partition is not empty, partition it with double pivot
            flagSort2(E, v.v1, v.v2, 0);
        // Last case: The only not-empty partition is white after partitioning with double pivot.
        // Description of the algorithm immediately implies that this consists of only one key value, thus is sorted.
    }
}
```

Special thanks to toto2, even though I don't pass the red/blue explicitly!

**MORE**: More randomness, because toto2 again totally has a point:

```
private static void flagSort(int[] E, int left, int right, int offset){
    if(left < right) {
        IntTuple v = partition(E, left, right, E[left + (offset % (right - left))], 
            E[left + ((2 * offset) % (right - left))]);
        if ((left != v.v1) || (right != v.v2)) {
            int random = rnd.nextInt(right - left);
            flagSort(E, left, v.v1 - 1, random);
            flagSort(E, v.v1, v.v2, random);
            flagSort(E, v.v2 + 1, right, random);
        } else if (offset > 0)
            flagSort(E, v.v1, v.v2, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Minor comment: `Random rnd = new Random();` should be a class member instead of being reinitialized every time flagSort is called.

Comment: @toto2 You're right, of course, but as this won't ever affect correctness, I happily scheduled it to be fixed later :)

Answer (score 0):

On each time you call your partition method, one simple thing happens :
The items at blue and red index are exactly where they belong.
so, when you call this part of your code :

```
    flagSort(E, left, v.v1 - 1);
    flagSort(E, v.v1, v.v2);
    flagSort(E, v.v2 + 1, right);
```

these calls must not contain blue and red,
in other words  :

```
 flagSort(E, left, v.v1 - 1);
 flagSort(E, v.v1 +1 , v.v2 -1);
 flagSort(E, v.v2 + 1, right);
```

Comment: I checked that by looking over my code and confirmed it by experiment: It is legal to endup with a single white (not red or blue) partition containing all elements in the array, as long as the pivots are upper&lower bound of all the elements.

If i did use your snippet, i would in that case strip the white partition by the 2 edge elements and put them into red/blue, even though the white partition is not yet sorted.

Answer (score 0):

```
IntTuple v = partition(E, left, right, rnd.nextInt(50), rnd.nextInt(50));
```

50?  You know the minimum-maximum (red-blue) values for the current partition, which is a narrower range than 0-49.  You should modify flagSort such that you pass it not only the left-right values, but also the red-blue values.

If flagSort is called with red == blue, you can just return since the sub-array has identical values and is already sorted.

Comment: I came up with a working solution, which is completely stripped off the random part, but feels sort of gruesome. Check back the OP in a few mins...

Comment: You are still using randomness when you call partition with E[left], E[left + 1], but you are using the randomness of the array.

Comment: I don't quite get your "dual" in your new solution.  In the comment after `if (dual)` you say you are using a double pivot, but you call a single one: E[left], E[left].  I don't see the use of using a single pivot if you have only a middle (white) array.  That array is just a normal array as any other: it can contain many different numbers.

Comment: Yupp, that's why I called it awkward... the "dual"/"double" pivot should only point out they're explicitly the same, as opposed to (most) other function calls. Pretty misleading, indeed...

Comment: You might still want to pass red-blue values and use Random(): your current method will perform as poorly as possible if it's given an already sorted array.